# Overview about AWS logs that can be used in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

As far as I understand there are special logs (like for EC2 Instances, RDS) which can be enabled to collect metrics and are not enabled automatically. Is there an OVERVIEW somewhere stating for which resources do special AWS Logs exist and how they can be enabled (via CloudFormation)?

If not I would suggest to create such an Overview since AWS DOCUMENTATION doesn’t have it.

Merci A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch collects metrics from AWS services that you use. (Or, more accurately, the services you use *send* metrics to Amazon CloudWatch.)

The documentation for each service shows the metrics that are collected.

The only logs that go beyond this are special ones sent from *within* an Amazon EC2 instance. By default, the Amazon EC2 service can only examine your *virtual machine* ('instance') from *outside* of the instance. This provides basic metrics for CPU, disk and network. It is not possible to see *inside* your instance.

However, if you run additional software *inside* the instance that communicates with the operating system, then the software can send additional metrics to Amazon CloudWatch. This is typically done with the **CloudWatch Agent**.

See: [Collect Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)

There are additional [Metrics Collected by the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html) that can provide details such as free memory and free disk space because the agent communicates with the Operating System running *inside* the instance. These metrics are then sent to Amazon CloudWatch as **custom metrics**.

The CloudWatch Agent can also send application logs from an Amazon EC2 instance to **Amazon CloudWatch Logs**, which retains the individual log entries and can trigger alarms based on their content.

The CloudWatch Agent must be installed into the Amazon EC2 instance, either via a startup script ('User Data' script) or via AWS Systems Manager.

Similarly, [Amazon RDS can send database logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html). However, I couldn't see an option in Amazon CloudFormation to activate these *log exports*.